# USB host mode with class compliant audio interfaces

Tags: audio, htc-evo, usb-connection-mode, usb-peripherals, usb-host-mode

I have an HTC EVO, and it is my understanding that the hardware supports USB host mode.  I am still working to confirm this, but even if it doesn't, I understand other devices do, and that the Android kernel supports USB2Go.

Assuming the hardware is capable, what would it take to get Android to use a USB audio interface?  I am only interested in trying to get it working for class-compliant interfaces, as anything else isn't worth the effort.

I understand this is a bit of an general question.  I am hoping someone has already tried this.  I'm a software developer but have not dug into Android much.  This would be a heavy first project for me, but any information on how/if this could even be done would be much appreciated.

**Edit:**  Seems this guy got it working on a Nexus One:  http://sven.killig.de/android/N1/2.2/usb_host/

**Edit #2:**  So, since there seem to be drivers available... how would I load them?  Is ADB the only way?  Is a kernel update required, or can I simply drop the modules in place and load them?  If a kernel update is required, can I replace the kernel without losing everything else?

Comment: I think this is to development-oriented to be here.  Try StackOverflow.  That said, if the hardware supports it then there's no reason it can't be done, as illustrated by it working on the N1.  You might want to talk to that guy!

Comment: @Matthew, given that it is working on the N1, I guess that means I need to figure out how to load device drivers.  Editing my question now...

Comment: I'm still inclined to say this is a development question, but you can't drop drivers in place that the kernel doesn't support.  You can update the kernel and replace it without problems in general, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, Android 5.0 properly supports class-compliant USB audio capture!  It doesn't seem to work in all applications, but many work just fine.  I just used my Zoom H4n on a Galaxy S6 with the getUserMedia test page on Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I think USB Audio support was initially built into Android 4.0 ICS but there may be earlier implementations and not every hardware that supports USB OTG and runs ICS+ supports USB Audio.

The capability of an Android device to handle USB audio mainly depends on the Kernel running on your System and your hardware being able to handle USB devices (USB host). Custom kernel and ROMs can void this. I have been able to connect (to my stock Samsung Galaxy Note 2):

1. an Alesis I/O4 USB Soundcard from Alesis (4in, 4out, phantom power)
2. a Harman/Kardon v1 USB speaker system and
3. a Shure x2u soundcard (1in, 2out, phantom power)

all playing stereo (Alesis could not be configured to play on all four channels) and the soundcards also record (alesis recording 4 tracks in sync) in very nice quality. I used [Urecord](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cc.co.eurdev.urecorder) (mono/ stereo) and [USB Audio Recorder PRO](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.extreamsd.usbaudiorecorderpro) (multitrack) and I have been told that Audio Evolution is also able to record from a USB source.