# how to enhance the sound quality while recording the sound?

Tags: audio

I want to enhance the sound quality while recording the sound on the android device, Is there and external device which is used for this. If yes then tell me for this I'll be thankful to you.

Comment: How are you recording currently and what are the problems your're facing?

Comment: you could use a USB Audio Interface and a USB OTG cable. have a look at [this post](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3611/usb-host-mode-with-class-compliant-audio-interfaces/60916#60916) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any ordinary microphone that uses unbalanced connectors with suitable adaptors like [this 3,5mm one](https://eu.startech.com/Cables/Audio-Video/Audio-Cables/35mm-4-Position-to-2x-3-Position-35mm-Headset-Splitter-Adapter-Male-to-Female~MUYHSMFF). However, the resulting quality will depend on the DACs of the device and the application used, an external mic can only do so much.

Comment: irig mic is used with iOS is it compatible for android?

Comment: Should be, but this depends on the device you're using.  See my answer [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23381/) for details.